# PySide6 Layout add space between items

Tags: python, layout, frontend, pyside6

I am using the [QVBoxLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout) from PySide6 to organize some items.

[image: UI]

I now want to add some more space between the "Search" button and the "Modbus Data" group box.
They are all located inside the same QVBoxLaxout.

Here is the code which creates the displayed UI.

```
    def setup_ui(self):
        v_layout_base = QVBoxLayout(self)

        h_layout_com_list = QHBoxLayout(self)
        h_layout_com_list.addWidget(QLabel("Modbus COM"))
        self.lw_com = QListWidget(self)
        h_layout_com_list.addWidget(self.lw_com)

        h_layout_search = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.button_search_com = QPushButton("Search")
        h_layout_search.addWidget(self.button_search_com)

        group_box = QGroupBox(QTranslator.tr("Modbus data"))
        v_layout_modbus_data = QVBoxLayout(self)

        h_layout_baudrate = QHBoxLayout(self)
        h_layout_baudrate.addWidget(QLabel("Baudrate"))
        self.cB_baudrate = QComboBox()
        h_layout_baudrate.addWidget(self.cB_baudrate)

        h_layout_bytesize = QHBoxLayout(self)
        h_layout_bytesize.addWidget(QLabel("Bytesize"))
        self.cB_bytesize = QComboBox()
        h_layout_bytesize.addWidget(self.cB_bytesize)

        h_layout_parity = QHBoxLayout(self)
        h_layout_parity.addWidget(QLabel("Parity"))
        self.cB_parity = QComboBox()
        h_layout_parity.addWidget(self.cB_parity)

        h_layout_stop_bit = QHBoxLayout(self)
        h_layout_stop_bit.addWidget(QLabel("Stop bit"))
        self.cB_stop_bit = QComboBox()
        h_layout_stop_bit.addWidget(self.cB_stop_bit)

        h_layout_connect = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.pb_connect = QPushButton("Connect")
        self.pb_com_search = QPushButton("Disconnect")
        h_layout_connect.addWidget(self.pb_connect)
        h_layout_connect.addWidget(self.pb_com_search)

        h_layout_com_label = QHBoxLayout(self)
        h_layout_com_label.addWidget(QLabel("COM:"))
        self.button_com_connect_label = QLabel("No COM selected")
        h_layout_com_label.addWidget(self.button_com_connect_label)

        h_layout_modbus_label = QHBoxLayout(self)
        h_layout_modbus_label.addWidget(QLabel("Modbus:"))
        self.button_modbus_connect_label = QLabel("Not connected to Modbus")
        h_layout_modbus_label.addWidget(self.button_modbus_connect_label)

        v_layout_base.addLayout(h_layout_com_list)
        v_layout_base.addLayout(h_layout_search, 100)
        v_layout_modbus_data.addLayout(h_layout_baudrate)
        v_layout_modbus_data.addLayout(h_layout_bytesize)
        v_layout_modbus_data.addLayout(h_layout_parity)
        v_layout_modbus_data.addLayout(h_layout_stop_bit)
        group_box.setLayout(v_layout_modbus_data)
        v_layout_base.addWidget(group_box)
        v_layout_base.addLayout(h_layout_connect)
        v_layout_base.addLayout(h_layout_com_label)
        v_layout_base.addLayout(h_layout_modbus_label)
```

Comment: [`addSpacing()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QBoxLayout.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addSpacing).

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you to consider reading the official C++ docs as they are a bit more comprehensive (for instance, they always indicate the class inheritance, which is not obvious from the python docs). Despite not intended for Python, the function definitions and arguments are the same 99.9% of the times, and the layout is better structured, giving an improved overview of the class. Also, for label/widget layouts, consider [QFormLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qformlayout.html)